# Creating groups and group handles in JList with drag and drop support

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, jlist

I've managed to create a JList with support of selecting multiple elements and dragging them to reorder the list. But I was wondering how to group some elements together with a handle. Something a lot like this:

[image]

Since even figuring out the drag&drop mechanics was so challenging to me, I'm hesitated to add this group feature. Is it even possible with JLists? What topic should I search to be able to do somthing like this?

Comment: Use a `JTree`.  That code is trying to force a square peg (`JList`) into a round hole (`JTree`).

Comment: @AndrewThompson I'm not familiar with JTrees, would the d&d be similar to JLists?

Comment: Alright, will have a look, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my JTree after learning about JTrees from Andrew Thompson. I found a JTree example from Craig Wood and tweaked it to suit my needs. It is still not 100% complete. It doesn't have any comments or explanations sorry for that, I'm just sharing my source code.

```
public class TreeDragAndDrop {

    final JTree tree = new JTree();
    DefaultTreeModel model = (DefaultTreeModel) tree.getModel();
    DefaultMutableTreeNode root = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) model.getRoot();

    private JScrollPane getContent() {
        tree.setDragEnabled(true);
        tree.setDropMode(DropMode.ON_OR_INSERT);
        tree.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(TreeSelectionModel.CONTIGUOUS_TREE_SELECTION);
        //expandTree(tree);

        tree.setEditable(true);

        tree.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0), "startEditing");
        tree.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F2, 0), "startEditing");

        model.reload();

        return new JScrollPane(tree);
    }

    private void expandTree(JTree tree) {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode root = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) tree.getModel().getRoot();
        java.util.Enumeration e = root.breadthFirstEnumeration();

        while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
            DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) e.nextElement();
            if (node.isLeaf()) {
                continue;
            }
            int row = tree.getRowForPath(new TreePath(node.getPath()));
            tree.expandRow(row);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(new TreeDragAndDrop().getContent());
        f.setSize(400, 400);
        f.setLocation(1200, 200);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

}

class TreeTransferHandler2 extends TransferHandler {

    DataFlavor nodesFlavor;
    DataFlavor[] flavors = new DataFlavor[1];
    DefaultMutableTreeNode[] nodesToRemove;

    private void renameNodes(JTree tree) {

        DefaultTreeModel model = (DefaultTreeModel) tree.getModel();
        DefaultMutableTreeNode root = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) model.getRoot();

        java.util.Enumeration en = root.depthFirstEnumeration();

        while (en.hasMoreElements()) {

            DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) en.nextElement();
            String nodeName = node.toString();
            int strLength = node.toString().length();

            if (nodeName.charAt(strLength - 1) == ')') {
                nodeName = nodeName.substring(0, (nodeName.indexOf("(")) - 1);
            }

            if (node.getChildCount() > 0) {
                node.setUserObject(nodeName + " (" + node.getChildCount() + ")");
            }

        }

    }

    public TreeTransferHandler2() {
        try {
            String mimeType = DataFlavor.javaJVMLocalObjectMimeType
                    + ";class=\""
                    + javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode[].class.getName()
                    + "\"";
            nodesFlavor = new DataFlavor(mimeType);
            flavors[0] = nodesFlavor;

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("ClassNotFound: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public boolean canImport(TransferHandler.TransferSupport support) {

        if (!support.isDrop()) {
            return false;
        }

        support.setShowDropLocation(true);

        if (!support.isDataFlavorSupported(nodesFlavor)) {
            return false;
        }

        // Do not allow a drop on the drag source selections.
        JTree.DropLocation dl = (JTree.DropLocation) support.getDropLocation();
        JTree tree = (JTree) support.getComponent();

        int dropRow = tree.getRowForPath(dl.getPath());
        int[] selRows = tree.getSelectionRows();

        for (int i = 0; i < selRows.length; i++) {
            if (selRows[i] == dropRow) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        // Do not allow MOVE-action drops if a non-leaf node is
        // selected unless all of its children are also selected.
        int action = support.getDropAction();
        if (action == MOVE) {
            return haveCompleteNode(tree);
        }

        // Do not allow a non-leaf node to be copied to a level
        // which is less than its source level.
        TreePath dest = dl.getPath();
        DefaultMutableTreeNode target = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) dest.getLastPathComponent();

        TreePath path = tree.getPathForRow(selRows[0]);
        DefaultMutableTreeNode firstNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) path.getLastPathComponent();

        if (firstNode.getChildCount() > 0 && target.getLevel() < firstNode.getLevel()) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private boolean haveCompleteNode(JTree tree) {

        int[] selRows = tree.getSelectionRows();
        TreePath path = tree.getPathForRow(selRows[0]);
        DefaultMutableTreeNode first = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) path.getLastPathComponent();
        int childCount = first.getChildCount();

        // first has children and no children are selected.
        if (childCount > 0 && selRows.length == 1) {
            return true;
        }

        // first may have children.
        for (int i = 1; i < selRows.length; i++) {

            path = tree.getPathForRow(selRows[i]);

            DefaultMutableTreeNode next = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) path.getLastPathComponent();

            if (first.isNodeChild(next)) {

                // Found a child of first.
                if (childCount > selRows.length - 1) {
                    // Not all children of first are selected.
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    protected Transferable createTransferable(JComponent c) {

        JTree tree = (JTree) c;
        TreePath[] paths = tree.getSelectionPaths();

        if (paths != null) {

            // Make up a node array of copies for transfer and
            // another for/of the nodes that will be removed in
            // exportDone after a successful drop.
            List<DefaultMutableTreeNode> copies = new ArrayList<DefaultMutableTreeNode>();
            List<DefaultMutableTreeNode> toRemove = new ArrayList<DefaultMutableTreeNode>();

            DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) paths[0].getLastPathComponent();

            int childCount = node.getChildCount();
            DefaultMutableTreeNode copy = null;

            if (node.getChildCount() > 0 && tree.getSelectionRows().length == 1) {

                copy = copy(node);
                copies.add(copy);

                for (int k = 0; k < childCount; k++) {
                    copy.add((MutableTreeNode) node.getChildAt(0));
                }

                toRemove.add(node);

            } else {

                for (int i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {

                    DefaultMutableTreeNode next = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) paths[i].getLastPathComponent();

                    // sibling
                    copies.add(copy(next));
                    toRemove.add(next);

                }
            }

            DefaultMutableTreeNode[] nodes = copies.toArray(new DefaultMutableTreeNode[copies.size()]);
            nodesToRemove = toRemove.toArray(new DefaultMutableTreeNode[toRemove.size()]);
            return new NodesTransferable(nodes);
        }

        return null;

    }

    /**
     * Defensive copy used in createTransferable.
     */
    private DefaultMutableTreeNode copy(TreeNode node) {
        return new DefaultMutableTreeNode(node, true);
    }

    protected void exportDone(JComponent source, Transferable data, int action) {

        if ((action & MOVE) == MOVE) {

            JTree tree = (JTree) source;

            DefaultTreeModel model = (DefaultTreeModel) tree.getModel();

            int[] ints = new int[nodesToRemove.length];

            DefaultMutableTreeNode parent = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) nodesToRemove[0].getParent();

            // Remove nodes saved in nodesToRemove in createTransferable.
            for (int i = 0; i < nodesToRemove.length; i++) {
                model.removeNodeFromParent(nodesToRemove[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    public int getSourceActions(JComponent c) {
        return MOVE;
    }

    public boolean importData(TransferHandler.TransferSupport support) {

        if (!canImport(support)) {
            return false;
        }

        // Extract transfer data.
        DefaultMutableTreeNode[] nodes = null;

        try {

            Transferable t = support.getTransferable();
            nodes = (DefaultMutableTreeNode[]) t.getTransferData(nodesFlavor);

        } catch (UnsupportedFlavorException ufe) {
            System.out.println("UnsupportedFlavor: " + ufe.getMessage());
        } catch (java.io.IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("I/O error: " + ioe.getMessage());
        }

        // Get drop location info.
        JTree.DropLocation dl = (JTree.DropLocation) support.getDropLocation();

        int childIndex = dl.getChildIndex();

        TreePath dest = dl.getPath();
        DefaultMutableTreeNode parent = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) dest.getLastPathComponent();
        DefaultMutableTreeNode superParent = null;
        int parentIndex = 0;

        if (parent.isLeaf()) {

            superParent = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) parent.getParent();
            parentIndex = superParent.getIndex(parent);

        }

        JTree tree = (JTree) support.getComponent();
        DefaultTreeModel model = (DefaultTreeModel) tree.getModel();

        // Configure for drop mode.
        int index = childIndex;    // DropMode.INSERT

        if (childIndex == -1) {     // DropMode.ON

            index = 0;

            if (parent.getChildCount() == 0) {

                DefaultMutableTreeNode newParent = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("New Group", true);

                for (int i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {

                    model.insertNodeInto(copy(nodes[i]), newParent, i);
                    //model.removeNodeFromParent(nodes[i]);
                }

                model.insertNodeInto(copy(parent), newParent, newParent.getChildCount());
                model.removeNodeFromParent(parent);
                model.insertNodeInto(newParent, superParent, parentIndex);
                model.reload();

            } else {

                for (int i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
                    model.insertNodeInto(nodes[i], parent, parent.getChildCount());
                }

            }

        } else {

            // Add data to model.
            for (int i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
                model.insertNodeInto(nodes[i], parent, index++);
            }

        }
        return true;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return getClass().getName();
    }

    public class NodesTransferable implements Transferable {

        DefaultMutableTreeNode[] nodes;

        public NodesTransferable(DefaultMutableTreeNode[] nodes) {
            this.nodes = nodes;
        }

        public Object getTransferData(DataFlavor flavor) throws UnsupportedFlavorException {

            if (!isDataFlavorSupported(flavor)) {
                throw new UnsupportedFlavorException(flavor);
            }

            return nodes;
        }

        public DataFlavor[] getTransferDataFlavors() {
            return flavors;
        }

        public boolean isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor flavor) {
            return nodesFlavor.equals(flavor);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `JTree` instead. Using a list is trying to force a square peg (`JList`) into a round hole (`JTree`).

See [How to Use Trees](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html) for details and working examples.

[image: JTree example]